# Standard deviation from lm in r

Tags: r

How do you get the standard deviation from a lm in R? `summary(model)` automatically prints the standard error, however in the litterature you a often supposed to report the standard deviation. The degrees of freedom is reported as 47 and 3423.

Comment: I am aware that normally when talking about standard error and standard deviation, the conversion factor is sqrt(N). However as the degrees of freedom in my case is 47 and 3424 I am unsure of the appropriate method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In R, residual standard error refers to the estimated standard deviation of errors. This phrasing is specific to R.

```
?summary.lm
```

Value -> sigma : "the square root of the estimated variance of the random error"

Comment: Not really an answer. Could you show an example to support your assertion?

Comment: It is vocabulary idiosyncrasy of the people who wrote the function lm(). I edited my answer to reference R help.